# mongodb running only while ssh connection is kept

Tags: mongodb

Hello I'm testing mongo experimental version, which doesn't have an installer and is ran from directory by putting ./mongod but the problem is that the process quits whenever I close my ssh connection. What I'm supposed to do to keep it running even after closing ssh connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start the `mongod` process as a background daemon you should run it with the parameters `--fork` (run as a daemon) and `--logpath` (a filename for log output).

You probably want to specify the `--dbpath` as well (unless you are OK with the default of `/data/db`).

So putting that together:

```
$ mongod --fork --dbpath /path/to/data --logpath /path/to/mongod.log    
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 64043
all output going to: /path/to/mongod.log
child process started successfully, parent exiting

$
```

After the server starts you will be returned to a command prompt.

If you want to shut down the server gracefully, log in via the `mongo` shell and run [`db.shutdownServer()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.shutdownServer/).

For more information see [Manage `mongod` Processes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) in the MongoDB Manual.

Comment: yup that's exactly what I wanted, dbpath alredy was altered by me so that's no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that it is not started as a daemon so when you close your ssh session it got HUP signal. You can avoid it by using:

```
nohup command-to-start-mongo &
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that's great option not only for mongo, worth remembering!